# Set Custom Domain Name in (New) Google Sites

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google Sites lets a user easily create a relatively simple website, defaulting to a URL at `https://sites.google.com/<project>/<site>` . The "old" (until major Sites revision approx 1/1/16) also allowed mapping a registered domain name (eg. www.example.com ) to the Sites URL. How does a user map a "custom domain name" (as Sites calls the registered domain name) with the "new" Sites that offers relatively more complex website features?

Answer (score 0):

New Google Sites now supports mapping (custom domain) `<subdomain>.<yoursite>.<extension>` to (Google Sites URL) `http://sites.google.com/<project-name>/<site-name>` . If using a domain registrar other than Google itself you might have to change the domain's zone file CNAME record at the registrar to resolve the newly mapped domain name, as the mapping form explains as it applies the mapping.

"Change a site URL": 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423

"Apps > G Suite > Settings for Sites > [Web Address Mapping]"
https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppDetails:service=Sites